# how can bind string values to html controls in angularJS

Tags: c#, html, angularjs

For Example in asp.net with c# we build string like

```
string str="<div>..in that tag we can use any type of controls..</div>";
```

we can bind the string as `htmlgenericController`, so is there any option like above in angularjs?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is, there is an example in [AngularJS Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml):

Controller:

```
angular.module('bindHtmlExample', ['ngSanitize'])
   .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.myHTML = 'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with ' + '<a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em>';
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
</div>
```

Output:

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <p>I am an <code>HTML</code>string with ' + '<a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em></p>
</div>
```